# Order "form", final calculation not computing

Tags: javascript, html

This is supposed to be a simple pure html, css and javascript order form with four fields for four different product. Users can adjust quantity and calculate totals for each product and for the final total. Everything is working except the final calculation and I have no idea why because it uses the same methods I used to calculate the individual totals.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Order Form</title>
    <style>
    #productOnePrice, #productOneName, #productOneQuantity, #productOneTotal, 
    #productTwoPrice, #productTwoName, #productTwoQuantity, #productTwoTotal,
    #productThreePrice, #productThreeName, #productThreeQuantity, 
    #productThreeTotal, #productFourPrice, #productFourName, 
    #productFourQuantity, #productFourTotal, #orderTotalButton, #orderTotal{
        height:20px;
        width:238px;
        float:left;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        outline: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .container {
        height:auto;
        width:1000px;
        float:left;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
        outline: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .quantityOne{
        text-align: right;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
<!-- Product One -->
        <div>
            <p id="productOneName"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productOnePrice"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productOneQuantity">
                <input id="quantityOne" type="number">
                 <button onclick="productOneTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productOneTotal"></p>
        </div>
<!-- Product Two --> 
        <div>
            <p id="productTwoName"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productTwoPrice"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productTwoQuantity">
                <input id="quantityTwo" type="number">
                 <button onclick="productTwoTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productTwoTotal"></p>
        </div>
<!-- Product Three --> 
        <div>
            <p id="productThreeName"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productThreePrice"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productThreeQuantity">
                <input id="quantityThree" type="number">
                 <button onclick="productThreeTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productThreeTotal"></p>
        </div>
<!-- Product Four --> 
        <div>
            <p id="productFourName"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productFourPrice"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productFourQuantity">
                <input id="quantityFour" type="number">
                 <button onclick="productFourTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productFourTotal"></p>
        </div>
<!-- Order Total --> 
        <div>
            <p id="orderTotalButton">
                 <button onclick="orderTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="orderTotal"></p>
        </div>
        <script>
/* Product One Total Function */
            document.getElementById("productOneName").innerText = "mp3";
            document.getElementById("productOnePrice").innerHTML = 1;
            function productOneTotal(price, quantity){
                price = 1;
                quantity = document.getElementById("quantityOne").value;
                document.getElementById("productOneTotal").innerHTML = 
 parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
            }
/* Product Two Total Function */
            document.getElementById("productTwoName").innerText = "Cassette";
            document.getElementById("productTwoPrice").innerHTML = 1;
            function productTwoTotal(price, quantity){
                price = 1;
                quantity = document.getElementById("quantityTwo").value;
                document.getElementById("productTwoTotal").innerHTML = 
 parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
            }
/* Product Three Total Function */
            document.getElementById("productThreeName").innerText = "Vinyl LP";
            document.getElementById("productThreePrice").innerHTML = 1;
            function productThreeTotal(price, quantity){
                price = 1;
                quantity = document.getElementById("quantityThree").value;
                document.getElementById("productThreeTotal").innerHTML = 
 parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
            }
/* Product Four Total Function */
            document.getElementById("productFourName").innerText = "T-Shirt";
            document.getElementById("productFourPrice").innerHTML = 1;
            function productFourTotal(price, quantity){
                price = 1;
                quantity = document.getElementById("quantityFour").value;
                document.getElementById("productFourTotal").innerHTML = 
 parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
            }
/* Order Total Function */
            function orderTotal(productOneTotal, productTwoTotal, 
productThreeTotal, productFourTotal){
                productOneTotal = 
document.getElementById("productOneTotal").value;
                productTwoTotal = 
document.getElementById("productTwoTotal").value;
                productThreeTotal = 
document.getElementById("productThreeTotal").value;
                productFourTotal = 
document.getElementById("productFourTotal").value;
                document.getElementById("orderTotal").innerHTML = 
parseInt(productOneTotal) + parseInt(productTwoTotal) + 
parseInt(productThreeTotal) + parseInt(productFourTotal);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target your total elements with .innerHTML instead of value.

```
productOneTotal = document.getElementById("productOneTotal").innerHTML;
```

That'll remove the NaN error you were getting. The

elements don't have a value so attempts to retrieve .value were returning undefined.

Comment: I swear I tried several times and it never worked until now. Thank you so much. I have been at this for hours. Ugh. I tried to give you an upvote but I'm so new they won't let me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Textbox, and other elements *.value* is used. and div elements gain value we have use *.innerHTML*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Order Form</title>
    <style>
    #productOnePrice, #productOneName, #productOneQuantity, #productOneTotal, 
    #productTwoPrice, #productTwoName, #productTwoQuantity, #productTwoTotal,
    #productThreePrice, #productThreeName, #productThreeQuantity, 
    #productThreeTotal, #productFourPrice, #productFourName, 
    #productFourQuantity, #productFourTotal, #orderTotalButton, #orderTotal{
        height:20px;
        width:238px;
        float:left;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        outline: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .container {
        height:auto;
        width:1000px;
        float:left;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
        outline: 2px solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .quantityOne{
        text-align: right;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
<!-- Product One -->
        <div>
            <p id="productOneName"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productOnePrice"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productOneQuantity">
                <input id="quantityOne" type="number">
                 <button onclick="productOneTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productOneTotal"></p>
        </div>
<!-- Product Two --> 
        <div>
            <p id="productTwoName"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productTwoPrice"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productTwoQuantity">
                <input id="quantityTwo" type="number">
                 <button onclick="productTwoTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productTwoTotal"></p>
        </div>
<!-- Product Three --> 
        <div>
            <p id="productThreeName"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productThreePrice"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productThreeQuantity">
                <input id="quantityThree" type="number">
                 <button onclick="productThreeTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productThreeTotal"></p>
        </div>
<!-- Product Four --> 
        <div>
            <p id="productFourName"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productFourPrice"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productFourQuantity">
                <input id="quantityFour" type="number">
                 <button onclick="productFourTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="productFourTotal"></p>
        </div>
<!-- Order Total --> 
        <div>
            <p id="orderTotalButton">
                 <button onclick="orderTotal()">Add</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="orderTotal"></p>
        </div>
        <script>
/* Product One Total Function */
            document.getElementById("productOneName").innerText = "mp3";
            document.getElementById("productOnePrice").innerHTML = 1;
            function productOneTotal(){
              
    
                price = 1;
                quantity = document.getElementById("quantityOne").value;
              if(quantity=="") {
                quantity = 0;
              }
                document.getElementById("productOneTotal").innerHTML = 
 parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
            }
/* Product Two Total Function */
            document.getElementById("productTwoName").innerText = "Cassette";
            document.getElementById("productTwoPrice").innerHTML = 1;
            function productTwoTotal(){
                price = 1;
                quantity = document.getElementById("quantityTwo").value;
                   if(quantity=="") {
                quantity = 0;
              }
              document.getElementById("productTwoTotal").innerHTML = 
 parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
            }
/* Product Three Total Function */
            document.getElementById("productThreeName").innerText = "Vinyl LP";
            document.getElementById("productThreePrice").innerHTML = 1;
            function productThreeTotal(){
                price = 1;
                quantity = document.getElementById("quantityThree").value;
                   if(quantity=="") {
                quantity = 0;
              }
              document.getElementById("productThreeTotal").innerHTML = 
 parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
            }
/* Product Four Total Function */
            document.getElementById("productFourName").innerText = "T-Shirt";
            document.getElementById("productFourPrice").innerHTML = 1;
            function productFourTotal(){
                price = 1;
                quantity = document.getElementById("quantityFour").value;
                  if(quantity=="") {
                quantity = 0;
              }
              document.getElementById("productFourTotal").innerHTML = 
 parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
            }
/* Order Total Function */
            function orderTotal(productOneTotal, productTwoTotal, 
productThreeTotal, productFourTotal){
              
                productOneTotal = 
document.getElementById("productOneTotal").innerHTML;
              
                productTwoTotal = 
document.getElementById("productTwoTotal").innerHTML;
                productThreeTotal = 
document.getElementById("productThreeTotal").innerHTML;
                productFourTotal = 
document.getElementById("productFourTotal").innerHTML;
              if(productOneTotal=="") {
                    productOneTotal=0;
               
              }
               if(productTwoTotal=="") {
                    productTwoTotal=0;
                 
              }
                if(productThreeTotal=="") {
                    productThreeTotal=0;
                  
              }
              if(productFourTotal=="") {
                    productFourTotal=0;
                 
              }
              
                document.getElementById("orderTotal").innerHTML = 
parseInt(productOneTotal) + parseInt(productTwoTotal) + 
parseInt(productThreeTotal) + parseInt(productFourTotal);
              
              }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```